# Google Sheets Color diferent cel strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to color my cels with 3 colors of text, is possible via conditional formating of JS? TY !

Example.

```
8♠ 6♦ 5♣
```

[image: 3 colors in one cell]

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: may u can help me? how I can 'split' text on script?

Comment: It looks like you can split on spaces

Comment: and you will probably need to us richtext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')

function changeColor() {
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
  const values = range.getValues()

  black = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setForegroundColor("black")
    .build();

  blue = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setForegroundColor("blue")
    .build();

  green = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setForegroundColor("green")
    .build();

  for (value of values){
    richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(value)
    .setTextStyle(0, 2, black)
    .setTextStyle(3, 5, blue)
    .setTextStyle(6, 8, green)
    .build();
    
    range.setRichTextValue(richText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to use the [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder) class.
You define the colors and then the positions that these colors take effect.

### Script example:

This will generate the desired result in the cell `A1` of `Sheet1`:

```
function changeColor() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
   var black = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("black")
      .build();

   var blue = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("blue")
      .build();

   var green = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("green")
      .build();

   var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText("8♠ 6♦ 5♣")
      .setTextStyle(0, 2, black)
      .setTextStyle(3, 5, blue)
      .setTextStyle(6, 8, green)
      .build();

   range.setRichTextValue(richText);
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: So ty alot man!
now I need to add it to a for loop
so where's my solution, 'not working'

@edit sorry I have to create a new comment :D